# Tweet button not appearing properly on blog

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

On my site [here](http://blog.austinevers.com/), the tweet button using code generated on Twitter.com works for the first few posts. Though after that, it fails to load and just shows the text.

I've been looking in the console for any JS errors but can't find any errors that might cause this.

May you please assist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time your loaded your comments, also call `twttr.widgets.load();` to force the twitter script to re-render all buttons.

Comment: Hey there! I'm not sure how I'd do this but I thank you for the help!

I've tried the following --

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    twttr.widgets.load();
    });

That didn't work though. Any advice?

Comment: some function loads your comments when theyre loaded. You have to call `twttr.widgets.load();` after that happened. You're having the Twitter script on your website, aswell as some divs/links by twitter. When your page loads, the twitter script will also execute that function and render the twitter buttons. But when you load your comments afterwards, there will only be the text that you're seeing. So you have to call the function after that.

Comment: I guess your autoloader.js loads the new comments. And since that script is minified and most likely not written by you, you'll have a hard time finding the right spot to add the twitter function, sorry